# Auth redirect isn't working. Prefix doesn't show

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, routes, prefix

Everything is working fine except when I try to open some link that requires authentication I get the wrong route.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
    Route::get('login', array('as' => 'admin.login', 'uses' => 'AdminAuthController@getLogin'));
    Route::post('login', array('as' => 'admin.login.post', 'uses' => 'AdminAuthController@postLogin'));
    Route::get('logout', array('as' => 'admin.logout', 'uses' => 'AdminAuthController@getLogout'));
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'admin.dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminWorksController@dashboard'));
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'admin.dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminWorksController@dashboard'));
    Route::resource('works', 'AdminWorksController', array('except' => array('show')));
});
```

So when I do `HTML::linkRoute('admin.login')` the output link is fine, but when I try to open a route in the group with the filter `'before'=>'auth'` without being logged in it redirects to `/login` instead of `/admin/login`.

Apart from that, everything works great. With the command `php artisan routes` looks good too.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this mistaken redirect of auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `auth` filter in `app/filters.php` to this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        return Redirect::guest(route('admin.login'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Completely forgot about that. Thanks. It's working now.